# Qt 5: CONFIG+=c++11 vs QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++11 (What's better)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, std

I know that if you want to add `C++11` features to your Qt code you need to write this line in your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11,
```

but also you can use instead of it this another line:

```
CONFIG+=c++11.
```

The question is: What's better to use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CONFIG+=c++11` is better because it is handled by `qmake` tool which knows how to set it properly while `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11` almost directly says to `qmake` to set `-std=c++11` flag to a compiler but it may not work because somewhere it is `-std=gnu++11` or even `-std=c++0x` so you may have a compiler error. So it is not only about having an error but about portability too.

From [the qt5-qmake documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#config):

> CONFIG
>
> Specifies project configuration and compiler options. The values are recognized internally by qmake and have special meaning.

Comment: That's right, however I tried to compile Qt5 code using CONFIG+=c++11 for using range based for with a Qt container (QList for being accurate) and I have got a compiler error, then I changed it for QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=gnu++11 and it worked perfectly. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Hm, it worked for me right at the time you asked the question.